# Show that if $|f(z)||z − z1| < \epsilon$ on $\partial R_0$, then $|\int_{\partial R_0}f(z)dz| \le 8\epsilon$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $R_0$ is a square centered at $z_1 \in \Bbb C$. Suppose that $f : U \to C$ is analytic,
where $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb C$ containing $R_0$. Show that if
$|f(z)||z − z1| < \epsilon$ 
on $\partial R_0$, then $|\int_{\partial R_0}f(z)dz| \le 8\epsilon$.

I got to this:

$$\left |\int_{\partial R_0}f(z)dz \right | \le \epsilon \int_{\partial R_0}\frac {dz} {|z-z_1|}$$.

I was stuck here. The solution I have said: "If we assume, as we may, that $R_0$ is a square with center $z_1$, elementary estimates show that $ \int_{\partial R_0}\frac {|dz|} {|z-z_1|} < 8$."

Why can you say that? Also, why do they have $|dz|$ and not just $dz$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are studying Goursat's proof of Cauchy's Theorem in Ahlfor's Complex Analysis, since when I pulled out my copy to make sure I was spelling Goursat's name correctly, there was exactly the sentence you've quoted (except for using $\zeta$ instead of $z_1$).

He has $|dz|$ instead of $dz$ because $dz$ can point in any direction, and contributions from one direction may cancel contributions from a different one. And for this same reason, your inequality is wrong. If you go back and look at the theorem, you will see that it is $\left | \int f\ dz \right | \le \int |f|\ |dz|$, not $\int |f|\ dz$. You should have the same integral on the right as Ahlfor.

You can assume that $R_0$ is a aquare centered on $z_1$ because in the proof in question, you get to choose where its sides are located, up to the restriction that $R_0$ is small enough that $|f(x)| \le \frac{\epsilon}{|z - z_1|}$. So just choose them symmetrically located about $z_1$, and equally separated in both directions.

Now let $2L$ be the sidelength of $R_0$. Since $z_1$ is the center of $R_0$, $|z - z_1| \ge L$ for any point $z \in \partial R_0$. Therefore ${1\over |z - z_1|} \le {1 \over L}$ and 
$$\int_{\partial R_0} \frac{|dz|}{|z - z_1|} \le {1 \over L} \int_{\partial R_0} |dz| = {1 \over L}8L = 8.$$

(Note that if the absolute value were removed from $dz$ in the last integral, the value would be $0$, not $8L$, but then the inequality would also not be true.)

Comment: Yes, I am studying from Ahlfor's book. Thank you.

Comment: One question: When you say the value of the integral would be 0 if the absolute value of $dz$ was removed, would that also be a sufficient proof? Or can you only say that knowing Cauchy's Theorem for a rectangle which is what we were trying to prove?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a proof, because what we can show about $f$ is $$\left |\int_{\partial R_0}f(z)dz \right | \le \epsilon \int_{\partial R_0}\frac {|dz|} {|z-z_1|}.$$ if you remove the absolute value from $dz$, this inequality is no longer true. So it doesn't matter that $ \int_{\partial R_0}\frac {dz} {|z-z_1|} = 0$, as it doesn't tell us anything about $f$.